# Run a python script using requirements with browser JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html

My main goal here is to execute a python script I have written when I run a function triggered through HTML. Here is how I have things currently set up:

I have a JavaScript File containing python run functions:

```
const PythonShell = require('python-shell').PythonShell;
class AHK {
   static async runScript() {
     PythonShell.run('/ahk/script.py', null, function (err) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('finished');
   });
}
module.exports = AHK;
```

I have my main.js file which would be the js code for the HTML to handle. I'd like for it to take in the module `AHK`. Something simple like this:

```
const AHK = require('./ahk');

function runFunction(x){
 if(x = 1)
    AHK.runScript()
 }
```

And then I have some HTML with a javascript tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let x =1; //this is just to show x is getting populated. In the actual code it's constantly changing values

async function predict() {
  if(x > 1)
    runFunction(x)
}
</script>
```

**Biggest issue I'm facing:**

I've become aware that browser javascript doesn't like requirements/modules. For example, the `main.js` file doesn't like having a requirement at the top. I've tried using things like requirejs, but I can't seem to figure out how to make something like this work. I basically need it so that when the requirement is met and the function `runFunction` is run, the python script is executed on my machine.

Important to note that this is all running for a personal project on my computer, so it will never not be local.

Comment: Use node/electron

Answer (score 0):

Make the application on your pc an API and use the web page to send a request to the API telling it which python script to run. I haven't used python too much but I believe you can make an API with it. Then you can just make buttons for each python program you want to run and have these buttons send a request to the API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).